# SQLite3 record validation

Tags: python, validation, sqlite, data-manipulation

I want my code to use an if statement to check which usergroup a user is in, and then call different functions for each user. My current code is as follows:

```
c.execute('SELECT * from users WHERE username=? AND password =?',
              (username_input, password_input))
    if c.fetchone() is not None:
        c.execute('SELECT usergroup from users WHERE username=? AND password=?',
                               (username_input, password_input))
        user_group = c.fetchone()
        for (usergroup,) in c:
            if user_group == 1:
                App.admin_login_successful(self)
            elif user_group == 2:
                App.user_login_successful(self)
            else:
                App.user_login_successful(self)
                # This shouldn't happen, as all records should theoretically contain a value for usergroup.
```

What should I do to make the comparison work, as my records do contain a value that is either 1 or 2, but the validation isn't working.

Comment: What do you get from `print(user_group)` before `for (usergroup,) in c:`? I'm not sure why you're making a tuple in your `for` loop.

Comment: I did for(usergroup,) in c: off of the recommendation of another user on here to prevent against SQL injection, but his answer wasn't super clear. When I do print i get ('2',)

Comment: You are _retrieving_ something from your database, so if there was going to SQL injection it would already have happened; I'm not sure that recommendation makes sense or it's been taken out of context. Get rid of the `for` loop (you use `fetchone()` so you only get 1 result) and change the `if`/`elif` checks to `if int(user_group[0]) == 1:` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't repeat the same sql query more than once.

```
funcmap = {1: self.admin_login_successful, 2: self.user_login_successful}
c.execute('SELECT usergroup from users WHERE username=? AND password=?',
          (username_input, password_input))
for (usergroup,) in c:
    funcmap[usergroup]()
```

If the query returns no usergroups, then the for-loop will not
execute its body.  If the `usergroup` is not 1 or 2, then
`funcmap[usergroup]` will raise a `KeyError`.  As you say, this
should not happen, but if it does the `KeyError` will let you
know.  You may wish to use a `try..except KeyError` statement
around `funcmap[usergroup]()` to handle the error in some other way (logging, better specific error message before exiting, etc.)

Note that depending on how you instantiated the `sqlite3` connection and how you set up the database table, `usergroup` may be a integer or a string. If it is returning a string, you may wish to ask another question about how to retrieve `usergroup`  as an integer.
Alternatively, you could change `funcmap` to expect strings as the dict keys:

```
funcmap = {'1': self.admin_login_successful, '2': self.user_login_successful}
```